# Continuity of Functions when two functions are equal

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f,g:[a,b]\to \mathbb{R}$ be continuous function. Define the set $E:=\{x\in [a,b]:f(x)=g(x)\}$.  Prove that if $\{x_n\}$ is any sequence in $E$ and $x_n\to x$, then $x\in E$.

Comment: I have a exam tomorrow and this question is really bothering me.

Comment: Please someone?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you prove the more general statement that if $h$ is a continuous function, then $h^{-1}(A) := \{ x : h(x) \in A \}$ is closed if $A$ is closed. One way to prove this is to start by proving that $h^{-1}(B)$ is open if $B$ is open, and then check that $h^{-1}(B^c)=(h^{-1}(B))^c$. (This last statement has nothing to do with analysis or topology, it's just a statement about sets.)

Now apply this statement with $h=f-g$ and $A=\{ 0 \}$.

Comment: I agree that this approach would be more efficient in a sense, but I've always enjoyed analysis more than topology.